# PHP class for GIT GUI with commit tree

Tags: php, git

I have a re-seller account (https://www.panthur.com.au/reseller) with PHP, GIT etc installed (scroll down that page for full specs).

On one of the cPanel accounts I have set a GIT server account up to host websites (there will be a few sites on different sub-domains) so that I can version control these sites and work with other devs in maintaining the sites.

I would like to set up something like manage.domainname.com to manage GIT. As part of this I would like to be able to do a few things like merge and branch (I will put this behind a login), as well as see a graphical tree of commits like what is in SourceTree. I would also like to swap between projects.

I have found some basic ones but they generally don't seem to have a large number of functions (most of the projects do not look to be under current development), and don't seem to have the option of the graphical tree. I will create the main page that will have the choice of repository dirs etc, but any suggestions to classes that may help with the graphical tree etc?

Answer (score 0):

**[For remote repo]**

Since you set your git server on your re-seller account, the features to view graphical tree etc need to develop by you if panthur don’t support the features.

**[For local repo]**

Also you can clone your git server locally, and then view local repo by Source Tree or TortoiseGit etc.

Comment: It is the remote server that I want it on, That's why I'm looking for something in PHP.